# Javascript multiple calls or 1 big one

Tags: javascript, performance

When calling back to the same server, at what point am I better off making one bigger call, versus multiple parallel requests.

In my particular case, assume that the server processing time (not including request processing, etc) is linear (e.g. 1 big call asking for 3 bits of data takes the same processing time as 3 smaller calls).

I know that if I have a 1000 calls, I am better off batching them so as to not incur all the network overhead.  But if I only have 2, I'm assuming parallel requests are probably better.

Is this right?
If so, where is the cutoff?

Comment: I cannot imagine a scenario where it's a good idea to nail the server 4000 times to do a very similar action.  You should hit it once, get your results, and parse the return data.

Comment: the cutoff is two. two at a time is too much.

Comment: Depends on the nature of the requests and responses.  If the data are related in nature, then single call should do, but if one call is to get app data and the other call is to get ads data (which is totally unrelated to the subject the user wants) then two calls makes more sense.  Also, I'm sure the server would reject clients making crazy hits to the server to prevent spams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It depends on a number of factors that are highly dependant on your setup. If performance is a huge concern of yours, I would run tests, either with a 3rd party application like Wireshark, or write some performance testing code on the server. In general though, limit your amount of parallel requests to under a handful if possible, by concatenating them.

---

In general, a few requests (in parallel) are okay. A modern browser will attempt to run them in parallel as much as possible over the TCP stream.

That being said, this starts to get bloated because *every single request* you make at your server using the HTTP/1.* protocol comes with headers, which can be huge, as they contain things like the referrer and browser cookies. The request body might be one character, but the request itself will be much larger.

Furthermore, the scenario changes with HTTP/2 (or even SPDY), the new transfer protocol. Requests over the wire here are treated differently, and don't always carry the extra weight of all the header metadata that normal requests do. So, if your server and browser support HTTP/2, you might be able to run more requests in parallel.

For the most part, though, you'll be running over HTTP/1.*, which means any more than a couple requests in parallel can see a serious performance impact (in the scenario you described for server processing time) for total completion time over one large load.

There's one other thing to consider though, too, which is application dependant: when does that data matter? If you batch what would have been a ton of small requests into one larger one, none of the return data will come back until the entire operation is complete server-side. If you need to display data more rapidly, or you want to load things step-by-step for slower network conditions, the performance trade-off might be worth it for multiple small requests.

Hope this explanation helps.

*Definitely read up on the [FAQ for HTTP/2](https://http2.github.io/faq/): they also cover some of the same performance issues you'll run into with HTTP/1.* in the scenario you described*